# How do I make this case-insensitive, in Python 3.4.3?

Tags: python, case, case-insensitive

When the user is asked to search for a word, I want it to be case-insensitive.

```
import string
usersentence= input("Please type in a sentence without punctuation: ")

usersentence = ''.join(ch for ch in usersentence if ch not in set(string.punctuation))
print (usersentence.upper())
for i in range(1):      # number of words you wont to search
    word= input("Please enter a word you want to search for in the sentence: ")
    words = usersentence.split(' ')
    passed = False      # Something to check if the word is found
    for (i, words) in enumerate(words):
        if (words == word): 
            print("your word appears in position(s): ")
            print(i+1)
            passed = True       # The word has been found

    if not passed:
        print("Sorry your word does not seem to be here")
```

Comment: use `.lower()` on both sides of the comparison?

Comment: Use `lower()` after each `input()`?

Comment: How do i repeat the code

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to split your sentence in separate words first. You can first check:

```
if word.upper() in usersentence.upper():
    wordlist = usersentence.upper().split('')
    solution = [i for i, sentword in enumerate(wordlist) if sentword == word.upper()]
```

Comment: how to I repeat the code when the user is done?

Comment: `while True:` and after that the rest of the code.
This will repeat untill True is not True anymore (make it a variable if you want it to jump out of this with statement at a certain condition)

Comment: not sure how to do that

Answer (score 1):

Your question sounds strange since your code partially contains the solution :-) ! You can either use str.upper() or str.lower() to compare strings with no case constraints, just as you print one of them using str.upper(). Your code should then contain lines transformed this way:

```
word=input("Please enter etc.").lower()  # or .upper(), as you wish
# ...
for (i, word_) in enumerate(words):
    if (word_.lower() == word):  # or word_.upper(), as you wish
```

Using str.lower() should keep track of any accentuated char (useful in many languages). As a French speaker, this is the method I recommand. But str.upper() should fit your needs also.
See section 3.13 of the Unicode Standard to get information on how lower() and upper() are working on special chars.

Comment: how to I repeat the code when the user is done?

Comment: See answer from Harwee! :-)

Answer (score 1):

use `string.lower()` while comparing strings

use `while` loop to repeat the code

use `break` to break a loop

```
while True:
    sent = raw_input("Enter Sentence: ").lower() #or upper()
    sent = sent.split()

    word = raw_input("Enter Word to search: ").lower() #or upper()
    indexes= []
    for idx,ele in enumerate(sent):
        if word == ele:
            indexes.append(str(idx))
    print ("Your word appears at indexes: "+", ".join(indexes))

    response = raw_input("Do you want to continue? Y/N: ").lower()
    if response == 'n':
        break
    else:
       pass
```

The above code asks for user inputs and then checks if the word exists in given sentence, it then asks for confirmation to continue or not. If the user says `N` or 'n' then the loop breaks and program exits. If user says `Y` or 'y' then it asks for sentence and word again.

Edit: Replaced `continue` variable name with `response`

Comment: how to I repeat the code when the user is done?

Comment: @JaredDavies what do you mean by when user is done? the code is repeating infinitely

Comment: After the code has finished sorry.

Comment: @JaredDavies do you want to ask user for a new sentence and a new word to search, or do you want to run the whole program again?

Comment: a new sentence and word

Comment: The above code does that, it has a `while True` loop implemented, whatever is inside the loop is repeated infinite times, and input for sentence and word is inside the loop so it asks user again in a loop. I suggest you to have a read about loops

Comment: so how does the user have another go?

Comment: i want it to ask the user if he wants another go and if he does, repeat it and if he doesn't, end it.

Comment: is says invalid syntax